# React library using default MUI theme instead of custom theme injected in parent react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### Current Behavior

I have a React library which uses mui theme(custom). It is used in a react app which injects the theme using theme provider but the library is using the default MUI Theme instead of the custom theme.

### Expected Behavior

It should use the custom theme provided in the react app instead of the mui default theme.

### Steps to Reproduce

Steps:

1. Create a library which uses custom theme.
2. Inject the theme in your react app.
3. Check if it is using the same theme.

### Context

Trying to build a library which inherits the theme from the parent react app.

### My Environment

```
 npx: installed 2 in 9.464s

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.13 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browser:
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1023.0), Chromium (92.0.902.84)
```